# Access Files on New Install of Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server

I've installed Ubuntu Server on a standalone server machine w/ 4 HD's (1 for the server install and 3 other Windows HDs).  The server machine is plugged into a LAN cable directly to the router.  I'm trying to access the 3 other Windows HDs from windows, ubuntu, and Mac machines but can't find out how to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Samba, which allows a Linux computer to share files and printers just like a Windows computer.  You'll need to install the `samba` package, and edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.  There is some documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html).

On an Ubuntu client, you should be able to use Nautilus to find the server and access the file shares.  A Windows client should have no trouble accessing the server, of course.  Macs probably have no problems accessing Windows file shares either.

Comment: Thanks.  I've used Samba to share files, but how do you use Nautilus to "find the server and access the file shares"?

Comment: In Nautilus you can either click on `Network` and browse around to find other computers, which is the easiest method if it works, or you can click on `Connect to Server` and type in the name of a server, such as `smb://fileserver`, where "fileserver" is the hostname of the other computer.  In that case `smb` means to use the Samba protocol.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting it (by clicking the check mark).